# TypeError: append() takes from 2 to 5 positional arguments but 8 were given

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a for loop that will iterate operations for some files. The for loop works just fine until it arrives at the append operation. It gives me the following error:

TypeError: append() takes from 2 to 5 positional arguments but 8 were given

How is it possible to fix this?

```
>>> index = 0

>>> for value in Sample:
...     data = read_file(value)
...     #operations 
...     #operations
...     #operations
...     Data =pd.DataFrame([[Car_Model, Car_Length, Car_Width, Car_Height, Car_Engine, Manufactured_Year, Purchased_Year]], columns=['Car_Model', 'Car_Length', 'Car_Width', 'Car_Height', 'Car_Engine', 'Manufactured_Year', 'Purchased_Year']) 
...     Data.append(Car_Model, Car_Length, Car_Width, Car_Height, Car_Engine, Manufactured_Year, Purchased_Year)
...     index += 1
```

Comment: Apparently, some of the eight values aren't there so your append cannot append them. You can use a try/except to catch the error, see: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp. Or, before you append them, just check if your variables are OK.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of `DataFrame.append` ([link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)):

```
DataFrame.append(other, ignore_index=False, verify_integrity=False, sort=False)
```

As you can see it expects 5 parameters. You are giving 8, which is too much and which is also stated in your error.

The elements to be appended are in the parameter `other` which has this description:

> **other**:  DataFrame or Series/dict-like object, or list of these

> The data to append.

**Warning**: The documentation also says that `append` is deprecated:

> Deprecated since version 1.4.0: Use concat() instead. For further details see Deprecated DataFrame.append and Series.append